# User Form Entry using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, forms, user-controls

So, I have a User Form which has the following things - an input box, a drop down, a submit button and the Close (X) button; in one workbook named "A".

I want to write a VBA code in a new workbook "B", which will open the user form in A, fill in the input box and the drop down using the values in B and then click the submit button on the form. Is this possible?

Note : I do not want to change the code already written behind the user form in workbook A.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers write their own code and share an issue with a specific problem they are having.  See "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]** and [edit] your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

In workbook "B" you need to use Application.Run to run the macro (see the Help for more details), passing the information with which you want to populate the UserForm:

```
Sub CallUserFormInOtherDoc()
  Dim aList() As Variant
  Dim wb1 as Workbook
  Dim wb2 as Workbook

  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
  Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook With UserForm")

  aList = Array(1, 2, 3) 'substitute your code to populate the array for the listbox
  wb2.Activate
  Application.Run "OpenPopulateUserForm", "abc", aList
  wb1.Activate
End Sub
```

In workbook "A" you need a module with the code that opens and populates the UserForm:

```
Public Sub OpenPopulateUserForm(tbVal As String, aList() As Variant)
  Dim f As UserForm1
  Set f = New UserForm1
  f.TextBox1.Text = tbVal
  f.ListBox1.list = aList
  f.Show
End Sub
```

Note that:

1. Both workbooks must be open
2. The UserForm will work on Workbook "A"

Comment: What if I don't want to make any changes to the workbook A. Not even adding a module etc. Is it possible even then?